# R Programming - Loop for Outliers detecting

Tags: r

I am trying to write R codes for detecting the outliers in my data set and each outlier row cut from my existing data set and saved in another data file.

I have a data set "Dummy" including 25 variable and i want to remove outliers row from this data set and saved this rows into another data file...

I have the following R codes for detecting outliers...

```
library(outliers)
for(i in 2:25)
{
  outlier[i]=outlier(Dummy[i], logical=TRUE)
  find_outlier[i]=which(outlier[i]==TRUE,arr.ind=TRUE)
  new_outlier[i]=Dummy[find_outlier[,i]]
}
```

When i am running this syntax for one variable it works properly but when i put this codes into loop it does not work. Is there a problem in the repeat loop?

Thanks!!

Comment: 1. can you run `dput(Dummy)` and add the result to your question? 2.  you should should rename your variable `outlier` as it has the same as your function `outlier`. 3 as you store the results in the i-th element of your variables: what kind of variables are they? Arrays? You should show how you define them in your question as well.

Comment: Although not the best practice, it is perfectly ok language-wise to have a variable and a function with the same name. It will only be ambiguous if you use higher-order functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a for loop to perform this operation.

```
Student <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Test1 <- c(45, 36, 41, 42, 15)
Test2 <- c(47, 42, 38, 34, 44)
Test3 <- c(39, 41, 35, 21, 48)
Test4 <- c(13, 45, 42, 35, 37)
Test5 <- c(36, 38, 42, 14, 47)
Dummy <- data.frame(Student, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5)
out <- outlier(Dummy[,2:6], logical=TRUE)
out <- cbind(FALSE, out)
# Actual outlier values
Dummy[which(out[,], TRUE)]
# Row and column numbers of the outliers
which(out[,], TRUE)
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example of you data?

Comment: Currently i m working on this type of data Names test 1 test 2 test 3 3 test 4 test 5
A 45 47 39 13 36
B 36 42 41 45 38
C 41 38 35 42 42
D 42 34 21 35 14
E 15 44 48 37 47
F 47 46 32 46 83
G 48 35 83 48 41
H 42 32 47 41 35
I 39 41 46 49 49
J 38 35 44 41 45
Here test is my variable name and A,B,C,D, is my Student name.This is the subset of my data set. this is record of 10 students in 5 different types of test. I want to find outliers in each test one by one, and remove outliers row from existing data set and saved in any other new data set.

Comment: Is it a data frame type? Can you provide the R code to generate the exact variable Namestest you're using?

Comment: my data frame is like this - test 1, test 2 ... are my variable name arranged in column wise, where as A, B, C, D... are students name. i want to check outlier for each row in each variable. write now i am using this syntax-  library(outliers)    
out <- outlier(Dummy, logical=TRUE)
Dummy[which(out[,], TRUE)]

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include part of your data, but as you can see, the logic I apply is the same.

Answer (score 0):

my data frame is like this - test 1, test 2 ... are my variable name arranged in column wise, where as A, B, C, D... are students name. i want to check outlier for each row in each variable. write now i am using this syntax-

library(outliers)
out <- outlier(Dummy, logical=TRUE)
Dummy[which(out[,], TRUE)]

Comment: Yes, it is okay. But i want to remove that outlier row from my data set and saved in any other data file, so how can i do?